# React CDatatable tableFilter is not working and showing No filtering results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, core-ui

cdatatable tableFilter is not working and not filtering the items

[image: The cdatable code is not working]

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: <CDataTable
                className="data_table"
                tableFilter={{ placeholder: "Type here" }}
                itemsPerPageSelect
                itemsPerPage={5}
                hover
                sorter
                items={MyProjectData}
                fields={fields}
                bordered

Comment: Cdatatable prop tableFilter is working in another table but not working in this page